# Deleting from PHP array and having indexes adjusted

Tags: php

If I have this array:

```
<?php

$array[0]='foo';
$array[1]='bar';
$array[2]='foo2';
$array[3]='bar3';

?>
```

And I want to delete the second entry (`$array[1]`), but so that all the remaining entries' indexes automatically get adjusted, so the next 2 elements whose indexes are 2 and 3, become 1 and 2.

How can this be done, or is there any built in function for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. One is to use [`array_values`](http://docs.php.net/array_values) after deleting the item to get just the values:

```
unset($array[1]);
$array = array_values($array);
var_dump($array);
```

Another is to use [`array_splice`](http://docs.php.net/array%5Fsplice):

```
array_splice($array, 1, 1);
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/array_splice). Note that this modifies the passed array rather than returning a changed copy. For example:

```
$array[0] = 'foo';
//etc.

array_splice($array, 1, 1);

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use array_merge with a single array

```
$array = array_merge($array);
print_r($array);
```

from php.net:
http://us.php.net/array_merge
If only one array is given and the array is numerically indexed, the keys get reindexed in a continuous way.